# Why does writing this program output me weird strings?

Tags: c

I am trying to code minesweeper in C. I started out with assigning the values to a 2D array then print it. I tried everything but it didn't work.

This happens in my sample output:

[image]

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Tile {
    unsigned char isMine : 1;
    char status;
};

int main() {
    struct Tile arr[9][9];
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char count = 10;
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (c = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(rand() % 81 + 1 < count && arr[i][c].isMine == 0 && count > 0) {
                arr[i][c].isMine = 1;
                arr[i][c].status = 'X';
                count--;
            } else if (arr[i][c].isMine == 0) {
                arr[i][c].status = '.';
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            printf("%c", arr[i][c].status);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: This loop looks very fishy: `for (c = 0; i < 9; i++)` `c` will never be changed.

Comment: Why check `.isMine==0` at all? You only visit each cell once anyway.

Comment: @Gerhardh Damn I need to be much more careful while writing code. Thanks.

Comment: If these are strings, then overwriting the null terminator isn't a great idea either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never visit any fields in your loops except the 1st column due to incorrect loop header:

```c
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (c = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(rand() % 81 + 1 < count && arr[i][c].isMine == 0 && count > 0) {
                arr[i][c].isMine = 1;
                arr[i][c].status = 'X';
                count--;
            } else if (arr[i][c].isMine == 0) {
                arr[i][c].status = '.';
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

This will leave all other fields uninitialized and when you try to print it, strange things may appear.

Also as you only visit each field once (or at least that seems to be your intention), there is no need to check `isMine` at all. If you initialize properly, it must be 0 anyway.

Which of course requires that you intitialize properly as already mentioned in David's answer.

The condition can be reduced a bit more as the first part (`..+1<count`) already implies that `count>0`. No need to check again.

Finally, `continue` as last instruction of a loop is not really useful.

Your code could look like this:

```c
    struct Tile arr[9][9] = {{0}};;
...
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            if(rand() % 81 + 1 < count) {
                arr[i][c].isMine = 1;
                arr[i][c].status = 'X';
                count--;
            } else {
                arr[i][c].status = '.';
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing i am trying to do is if it doesnt generate enough mines(like if it generates 7 mines) I want it to continue the loop until the count becomes '0' I tried if (count == 0) {break;} else if (i == 8) {i = 0;} but a infinite loop happens. What am I missing again I wonder...

Comment: That is not what will happen. `continue` just starts the next iteration of the current loop. I.e. the outer loop will continue with next iteration. It will not repeat the current iteration.

Comment: I guess you will only get half of the mines you want. You should not compare with `<count` but always compare with initial value. Given a chance of `10/81` per field you will end up close to 10 mines for 81 fields. If you reduce the chance from `10/81` to `9/81`, ...`1/81` you will end up with much less in total.

Comment: It worked. I think I should be more careful while writing code. How did I think giving a "1/81" chance to the last mine would be a good idea? Much thanks for your anwser.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the array:

```
struct Tile arr[9][9] = {{0}};
```

otherwise you read an uninitialized value (leading to undefined behaviour) in:

```
        } else if (arr[i][c].isMine == 0) {
            arr[i][c].status = '.';
        }
```